# SQL to BigData Migration?

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, hadoop, hive

In our running project,Using ASP.net 3.5 with C# and MS SQL, Currently its database size become 4 TB. It will increase gradullay , so we are looking for a solution. Some 1 told me to about BigData (use Hive + Hadoop).
And he was giving the following refernce
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/398563/Analyzing-some-Big-Data-Using-Csharp-Azure-And-Apa
I was read these 2 link, but unfortunatel am not understanding what they meand!!!.
So any 1 explain me how can i do this? shall i migrate MSSQL to Hadoop?
Please tell the Hardware and software requirements for changing to hadoop? Is it possible to migrate our current database to hadoop? i have read some ware its using for mainly searching data and its not supporting multitransaction?
If possible to migrate then how much we want to work with our existing project?
Over this much TB , per sec we have 400-500 Data insertion and transaction are there

Comment: A few terabyte should not be a reason to switch to a different database. MS SQL should be able to handle it without problems. What is your "problem" with the size? Performance? Inserting/updating or selecting data?

Comment: Performance,  and dont think 4 TB is our actaul size its only 3 months backup  size, we want to kept it min 3 year, so size will be its 10 times

Comment: Well I wouldn't consider switching until you reach 5000+ TB. Even then  I would create a backup every few years instead of switching. Make sure you DB design is correct. Don't use 2 many triggers. Have your keys and indexes optimal for performance. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx for MSSQL specifations.

Comment: Means stay with sql and check performance Ok thanks ur help. But can u tell me about hadoop and above asking questions answer, for studying purpose?

Comment: in u r giving link showing File size (data)= 16 TB. So what i will do after this 16 TB.(we must kept 3 year data)

Comment: Sorry I can not, because I have never used it. The file size is not the database size. Database size limit is: 524,272 terabytes

Comment: I have 1 more doubt if SQL size is 524,272 then why these peples are using Big Table . Because in google i have seend so many refernce. Is it mainly for search engines? or for whom?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll share some of my experience. First of all I would analyze whether Hadoop fits into my requirements or not. Hadoop is not a replacement for traditional RDBMSs. It is meant for totally different purpose which is `offline batch processing` unlike RDBMSs which are used for real time queries. So, if you have real time needs you better think again. In such a case you would require something like [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org).

The first link which you have shown here is about [Hive](http://hive.apache.org). Hive is a data warehouse which runs on top of an existing Hadoop cluster. Along with that it also provides you an SQL like interface which makes it easier for you to query in an easier and convenient manner, in case you are coming from SQL background. Hive stores the data as Hive tables on top of HDFS(the Hadoop file system). But again Hive is not suitable for real time stuff. If you want to perform real time queries on your Hadoop data you might find [Impala](http://hive.apache.org) a good fit.

The second link shows you how to use Apache Hadoop with C# and Microsoft Windows Azure. Azure is Microsoft's cloud platform offering. You can find more on this [here](https://www.hadooponazure.com/). This link shows you how to write a [MapReduce](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/mapred_tutorial.html) program. MapReduce is a computation framework that allows you to process huge amounts of data on a cluster of machines in a distributed and parallel manner.

Originally Hadoop was developed to be used with Linux. But now you have the flexibility to use it with Windows as well, courtesy solutions like Azure and [HDP](http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworksdataplatform/).

Hadoop does not require any special software(apart from the basic things like ssh, appropriate language translator etc) or sophisticated hardware. It was meant to run on commodity hardware. But you might wanna keep the specs prescribed the vendor, you are going to follow, in mind.

You could easily move your SQL data into your Hadoop cluster either by writing your own programs or by more high level tools like [Sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org).

Search is not the only area where Hadoop is used. This is a very good [link](http://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/20100806-cloudera-10-hadoopable-problems-webinar-4931616) which tells us about the common problems that can be solved using Hadoop.

Hope this answers some of your questions. Let me know if you have any further query.

---

In response to your comment :

Hadoop is basically 2 things-a distributed filesystem(HDFS) and a processing framework(MapReduce). Being a filesystem it lacks random read/write capability. This is where a database, like HBase, comes into picture. Also, Hadoop stores data as files and not as columns which HBase does.

If you want to query your data stored in HDFS through Hive you map your HDFS files as tables in Hive and query them using HiveQL. Suppose you have a file called 'file.txt' in HDFS which has 2 fields number and name, you would do something like this :

```
hive> CREATE TABLE demo (no INT, name STRING);
hive> LOAD DATA INPATH '/file.txt' INTO TABLE demo;
hive> Select * FROM demo;
```

Comment: Thanks for u r valuble advice. I have understand this much Hadoops is not a Database ,Its a distributed data storage(Means not any table structure but store column oriented structre).And top of hadoop we can use Hive for quering. Is it ok? then why you prefer HBASE its also a Column oriented data structure? Now i want to create a simple table in Hadoop and i want to quering it back (Simple Select Query). Can u help me ? If possobile please show me a   example!!!. I heard throgh this link http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/ we will get a haddop platform is it possible?

Comment: Ok thaks ,But i have 1 more doubt HDFC (File System) u told it physically look like a txt file, so i can imagine it has no column. But in case of HBASE how its look physically?http://hortonworks.com/products/sandbox-instructions/ for hadoop is it a helpfull link?

Comment: Files in HDFS are just like files in any other FS..rows and columns come into picture when you map this file to a Hive table..it's totally upto you how you want to visualize that file..and Hive is not limited to just text files.

Comment: Ok ,what abt i have shown link  http://hortonworks.com/products/sandbox-instructions/

Comment: it is about Hortonwroks's hadoop offering. tells you how you can run Hortonworks Sandbox VM. i think first you need to decide which vendor are you going to choose.

Answer (score 0):

As many others pointed out, a 4TB database is not a reason to move to to Hadoop + Hive. There has to be a pain point that you can't solve with Ms SQL to look for options.

Just as a thought, have you considered moving to Azure so that your infrastructure can grow with you?

Answer (score 0):

I think Sqoop is the tool what you need to import data from MS SQL Database into Hadoop File System. It can follow which data was already imported from which table, so it will not import the data again.

Here is how it works:

```
sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://<IP>;username=dbuser;password=dbpasswd;database=<DB>' --table <table> --target-dir /path/to/hdfs/dir
```

Records can be stored as text files (one record per line), or in binary representation as Avro or SequenceFiles.

With `sqoop export` command you can export back into MS SQL Server from HDFS.